Is there a way to enable LWIP while using RTOS ThreadX?
How can I use both RTOS and LWIP in the same project? Enabling the CPU DCache did not help. I need it for ethernet. If it's impossible then can you tell a better solution? Here is the warning message.

I am using an STM32H743ZI MCU and STM32CubeIDE 1.16.1.

As far as i know LWIP works only with FREERTOS. So you should choose FREERTOS instead og Azure.

You can add LwIP or your favorite RTOS as a library to your project by cloning the Github repository, instead of generating all code with Cube MX. After, you can generate configuration files within multiple test CubeMX projects located at different disk paths: for AzureRTOS and LwIP and after move only configuration files into your project folder possibly adjusting them.
By default, LwIP is not specific only for FreeRTOS, so you can edit the generated configuration file to replace Freertos functions to ThreadX, etc
